# How to handle ordering of flask error handlers

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

How does one ensure that the flask error handlers get the most specific exception?

From some simple tests and looking at the source code, it looks like the flask error handling code just takes the first register error handler for a given exception type instead of the most specific type possible.

I guess the answer is to put the error handler for `Exception` at the very end?

Answer (score 7):

Error handlers follow the exception class *MRO*, or method resolution order, and a handler is looked up in that order; the specific exception type first, then it's direct parent class, etc, all the way down to `BaseException` and `object`.

There is no need to order anything; if you registered a handler for `Exception`, then it'd be used for any exception for which no more specific handler was found.